# Biconvex problem whose objective function depends on only one variable

Tags: optimization, constrained-optimization, convex-optimization

I am solving the following biconvex problem:
$$\min_{x,y} f(y)$$
$$s.t. ~~ g(x) \leq 0$$
$$~~~~~h(x,y) = 0$$
$$x \in X, y \in Y$$
where $X$ and $Y$ are compact convex sets, $g(x)$ and $f(y)$ are convex and $h(x,y)$ is affine for fixed $x$ or $y$. 
I wonder if there is any efficient algorithm to solve this type of optimization problem, not restricted to algorithms for general biconvex optimization problems.